# Does pg-pool-II support two phase commit?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

When pg-pool II is used with sharding, what happens if I want to do a transaction which involves two nodes ? Does pgpool support two phase commit ?

Comment: If you can use begin, end block or prepare transaction data will be committed to appropriate nodes.